# CSC error CS0006: Metadata file '......dll' could not be found - But file exists

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild, teamcity, csc

> CSC error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'C:\BuildAgent\work\cbcbc45410f50008\Output\bin\Release\abc.xyz.dll'
>   could not be found.

On a teamcity build that worked fine until now, the build starts intermittently failing for the CS0006 error.

I see a lot of posts about the projects build ordering related cause for this issue. But I doubt if this one is related to build orders as I see that they are set right. Also the build configuration and platforms are mentioned right in the project file and on invocation of the msbuild. Moreover the abc.xyz.dll exists on the file system with a creation time earlier than the failure time.

I have a feeling that it is some CPU or thread race condition. I say this because when it was consistently failing, I added file access auditing on the dll file, as the build was running. But then this time the build would succeed. I thought I was loading the processor differently by doing some work on the same agent.

I believe I am not alone. Thanks for any answers or directions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this by removing the project reference and then adding it back in again.